# R - Apply function on multiple data frames

Tags: r, function, apply, dimensions

I loaded several data sheets as data frames in R with:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Now I would like to apply a function on all data frames.
I thought about something like:

```
kappa1_mean_h_stem <- lapply(df.list, mean_h_stem)
```

Where `df.list` contains a list of all data frames.

```
    mean_h_stem <- function(x) {
  mean(x[1,3])
}
```

I want the function to return the mean for a specific column. But it tells me, I had the wrong number of dimensions.

Comment: Do you expect `kappa1_mean_h_stem` to contain a single mean across all data frames, or one mean per data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is I think that you passed `x[1,3]` which would get the value from the first row of the third column only. I assume you want to calculate the mean of the same column across all the `data.frames`, so I made a slight modification to your function so you can pass data and the name or position of the column:

```
mean_h_stem <- function(dat, col){ mean(dat[,col], na.rm=T)}
```

Column can be selected using an integer:

```
lapply(df.list, mean_h_stem, 2)
```

Or a column name, expressed as a string:

```
lapply(df.list, mean_h_stem, 'col_name')
```

Passing the second argument like this can feel a little unintuitive, so you can do it in a clearer way:

```
lapply(df.list, function(x) mean_h_stem(dat = x, col ='col_name'))
```

This will only work for single columns at a time per your question, but you could easily modify this to do multiple.

As an aside, to read in the csv files, you could also use an `lapply` with `read.csv`:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
df.list <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

Comment: First of all: thanks a lot! Now it worked the way I tried to achieve :]
Is it possible that the data frames are in a different order than they have in the folder? Cause they differ from the ones in my directory.
Edit: Okay, they differn in order, but that´s fine. It´s only that the figures are rounded a bit. Is there something I can add to prevent that and to get the actual figures with all decimal points? :]

Comment: @Shugojin - if A. Fowler's answer solved your problem, please accept his answer by clicking the check mark next to it. It's good etiquette to accept the answer that solved the problem, as well as to upvote helpful answers once you have sufficient reputation.  A.Fowler - nice answer, upvoted.

Comment: @Shugojin - to sort rounding issues, you could wrap `mean()` in `round()` e.g. `round(mean(dat[,cols], na.rm=T),1)` which would round the values to 1 decimal place. Thanks @LenGreski

Answer (score 0):

An unclear part of the question is whether the mean of a given column should be calculated after extracting the column across all data frames, or once per data frame.

Techniques described in the other answer will return a list of means calculated once per file. If the intent of the question is to extract a column across all data frames, then calculate a mean, we'd need to extract first, `unlist()` the result, and use it as input to `mean()`.

We illustrate this with [Pokémon stats](https://github.com/lgreski/PokemonData) data that I maintain on Github.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/PokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip",exdir="./pokemonData")

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",pattern="*.csv",
                              full.names=TRUE)
dataList <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,read.csv)
```

At this point `dataList` is a list of 8 data frames, each containing the statistics for one generation of Pokémon, which we can inspect with the RStudio Environment Viewer.

[image]

If we want to find the `mean()` of the `Attack` stat by generation, we can use `lapply()` as follows.

```
lapply(dataList,function(x,y) mean(x[[y]]),"Attack")
```

Here we use an anonymous function with two arguments, `x`, and `y`, where `x` represents the data frames in `dataList`, and `y` represents the column `Attack`.

This returns a list of 8 means.

```
> lapply(dataList,function(x,y) mean(x[[y]]),"Attack")
[[1]]
[1] 72.91391

[[2]]
[1] 68.26

[[3]]
[1] 73.93617

[[4]]
[1] 79.99138

[[5]]
[1] 82.44242

[[6]]
[1] 94.92366

[[7]]
[1] 86.5082

[[8]]
[1] 83.66387
```

What if the desired result is a single mean for `Attack` across all 8 data frames?

In that case, we can use `lapply()` to extract the desired column, `unlist()` the result to create a numeric vector, and pass that as an argument to `mean()`.

Given how R can nest functions, we can accomplish this in a single line of code.

```
mean(unlist(lapply(dataList,function(x,y) x[,y],"Attack")))
```

...and the output:

```
> mean(unlist(lapply(dataList,function(x,y) x[,y],"Attack")))
[1] 80.46699
```

### Augmenting the results

Given some of the comments on the question and answers, I thought I'd illustrate how we might generate a result that's a bit easier to consume than a list of numbers.

If we assign a name to each data frame when we create the initial list, we can then use the names to drive subsequent processing, including name information in an output data frame.

```
# assign names to dataList
df_names <- paste0("gen_",sprintf("%02d",1:8))
names(dataList) <- df_names
```

Once the names have been assigned, we can use the `df_names` vector to drive `lapply()` with an anonymous function.

```
resultList <- lapply(df_names,function(x,y) {
     df <- dataList[[x]] # use [[ to return a data frame vs. list()
     theMean <- mean(df[,y],na.rm=TRUE) # use [,] extract for variable substitution
     result_df <- data.frame(x,theMean)
     names(result_df) <- c("dataFrame",paste0("mean_",y))
     result_df 
 },"Attack")
```

At this point, `resultList` is a list of 8 data frames, each containing one observation. we use a combination of `do.call()` and `rbind()` to combine the data frames into a single output data frame.

```
# combine into single dataframe
do.call(rbind,resultList)
```

The resulting data frame allows us to see which mean belongs to each input data frame.

```
> do.call(rbind,resultList)
  dataFrame mean_Attack
1    gen_01    72.91391
2    gen_02    68.26000
3    gen_03    73.93617
4    gen_04    79.99138
5    gen_05    82.44242
6    gen_06    94.92366
7    gen_07    86.50820
8    gen_08    83.66387
```

**NOTE:** I generated the list of data frame names based on my knowledge of the contents. One could also use `list.files()` with `full.names = FALSE` to generate the names.

Comment: A good counter question. I should have mentioned it in my post. Despite the fact that I indeed wanted all means separate per data frame, it´s good to know how I could implement it for an overall mean ^^ And I really liked your Pokémon-Data-Samples ;]

Comment: @Shugojin - thanks for the feedback. Based on the question you asked relative to the other answer, I posted some additional code to illustrate how you might combine assignment of names to each data frame with an anonymous function and `lapply()` to add data source labels to the output vector of means, converting the result into a data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the further information. It´s really helpful!
But how do I add conditions for selecting data from specific rows or columns? Like getting the mean of the values lower than a specific threshold?

Comment: Nvm, I think I built a function that filters specific values from the column I want. It´s not beautiful - and won´t win prizes either - but it works I guess!