# How to iterate a function along a single column across multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

**EDIT:** I'm editing my original question because the solution offered works perfectly but not on my data frames (both in this example and in real life) but I can't figure out why, so I am including a reprex.

My original question: I have many data frames with identical column names (spectrophotometer data) and I want to apply a function along a *single* column of all the data frames at once, and append each data frame with the new column.  That single column is named the same across data frames.

I have been trying lapply (and apply family) and then moved on to map to no avail.  This solution seemed promising ([R - Apply function on multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028797/r-apply-function-on-multiple-data-frames)) but everything I put in position 3 inside the lapply function is ignored as an unused argument.

I want to create a new column (cold) by applying a calculation to a column (colc) for each data frame in a list of data frames.

This is the solution which is exactly what I need however I can't get it to work in real life - my reprex follows

```
library(tidyverse)
sizes <- c(3, 3, 3)
dfs <- lapply(setNames(sizes, paste0("df", seq_along(sizes))),
              function(n) data.frame(cola = sample(1:3, n, replace = T),
                                     colb = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), n, replace = T),
                                     colc = runif(n, 2, 10)))
calculation <- function(x){
  b <- 20
  abs <- log10(x/b)
  return(abs)
}

dfs %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(cold = calculation(colc)))
#> $df1
#>   cola colb     colc       cold
#> 1    3    x 7.849806 -0.4061711
#> 2    1    z 2.570162 -0.8910696
#> 3    3    y 4.787902 -0.6208847
#> 
#> $df2
#>   cola colb     colc       cold
#> 1    3    z 9.408709 -0.3275000
#> 2    1    z 8.979679 -0.3477692
#> 3    2    x 4.256270 -0.6720008
#> 
#> $df3
#>   cola colb     colc       cold
#> 1    2    x 7.283048 -0.4387168
#> 2    2    x 9.513528 -0.3226884
#> 3    2    z 7.552567 -0.4229354

lapply(dfs, function(df) df %>% mutate(cold = calculation(colc)))
#> $df1
#>   cola colb     colc       cold
#> 1    3    x 7.849806 -0.4061711
#> 2    1    z 2.570162 -0.8910696
#> 3    3    y 4.787902 -0.6208847
#> 
#> $df2
#>   cola colb     colc       cold
#> 1    3    z 9.408709 -0.3275000
#> 2    1    z 8.979679 -0.3477692
#> 3    2    x 4.256270 -0.6720008
#> 
#> $df3
#>   cola colb     colc       cold
#> 1    2    x 7.283048 -0.4387168
#> 2    2    x 9.513528 -0.3226884
#> 3    2    z 7.552567 -0.4229354
```

My (plodding) data frames:

```
library(tidyverse)
cola <- c(1,2,3)
colb <- c("x","y","z")
colc <- c(1.4,1.2,2.5)
mydf1 <- as.data.frame(colb %>% cbind(cola, colc))
colc <- 1.1*colc # just to change content of same column name for df2
mydf2 <- as.data.frame(colb %>% cbind(cola, colc))
mydfs <- list(mydf1, mydf2)

calculation <- function(x){
  b <- 20
  abs <- log10(x/b)
  return(abs)
}

mydfs %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(cold = calculation(colc)))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cold`.
#> ℹ `cold = calculation(colc)`.
#> x non-numeric argument to binary operator
lapply(mydfs, function(df) df %>% mutate(cold = calculation(colc)))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cold`.
#> ℹ `cold = calculation(colc)`.
#> x non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I know this is a hideous way to create data frames but it produces the same error in real life which are data frames imported from csv files.

What is the difference/problem here?
[image: str() of actual data]

Comment: You want a function, that takes a data.frame and a column name and apply this funcion on multiple data.frames in a list? Your `calculation`-function only takes one argument...

Answer (score 1):

Simply `lapply` a function to your list of dataframes, that modify each dataframe in turn.

```
# First, build a few random datasets for testing purposes.

sizes <- c(10, 20, 30)
dfs <- lapply(setNames(sizes, paste0("df", seq_along(sizes))),
              function(n) data.frame(cola = sample(1:3, n, replace = T),
                                     colb = sample(c("x", "y", "z"), n, replace = T),
                                     colc = runif(n, 2, 10)))

# Define your computation function.
calculation <- function(x) log10(x - 2)
# Note the function has to be vectorized.
# Wrap it with Vectorize if necessary, for instance:
# calculation <- Vectorize(function(x) log10(x - 2))
```

If your `colc` is a character variable holding numbers, you will have to convert it to numeric first. For instance:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

dfs %<>% mutate(colc = as.numeric(colc))
```

The point is, you can't apply your calculation directly to a dataframe, it applies to a vector. Here are ways, to return a list of the modified dataframes:

```
library(tidyverse)

dfs %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(cold = calculation(colc)))

lapply(dfs, function(df) df %>% mutate(cold = calculation(colc)))

lapply(dfs, function(df) within(df, cold <- calculation(colc)))

lapply(dfs, function(df) { df$cold <- calculation(df$colc); df })
```

---

With the sample dataframe

```
spec_tbl_df <- data.frame(Wavelength = c(187, 187, 188, 188, 188),
                          Intensity = c(-79.398, -80.068, 1.602, -2.068, 0.602))

# List of dataframes, with only one dataframe.
dfs <- list(spec_tbl_df)

calculation <- function(x) log10(x / 20)

library(tidyverse)

# Say you want to apply the calculation to Wavelength
dfs %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(Wavelength2 = calculation(Wavelength)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works with the way you set up the data frames but when I use it actual data in the same way I get:  Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character" OR Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cold`.
ℹ `cold = calculation(colc)`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator.  I can't work out why it is perceiving the same inputs differently.  Can you help clarify?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes even if you use my plodding method of creating 2 data frames and putting them in a list as above in original post, I get that error.  Actually the only way I get it to work is using your method of creating data frames and list.  I have looked at all angles of whether there is some kind of formatting difference between the data frames and list by the 2 methods.  The only thing I identify is my list of data frames returns this style of notation [[1]] and [[2]] for the 2 data frames in my example, whereas your method uses $df1, $df2.  Other than that, I can't find a difference

Comment: @user16469993 The problem occurs much earlier: when you are calling `cbind` on vectors, R builds a matrix. Since all columns of a matrix must have the same type, and one of them is a character vector, the whole matrix is converted to character, and you end up with a dataframe with character variables, on which the computation fails. The solution: build you dataframes the usual way. It will also work if you apply `as.data.frame` to a list of vectors, as list may have heterogeneous entries. Or you may also call `cbind`, but on a dataframe.

Comment: I did apply `as.data.frame` but the error I get with these ugly data frame builds are the same as real life attempts which are data frames imported from csv files.  I having been trying to figure out why it works perfectly on the data frames you supplied, but not on mine nor on my actual data.  I added a reprex to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @user16469993 You still don't understand. `colb %>% cbind(cola, colc)` converts everything to character if one of cola, colb, colc is character. The error is on *your* part, if you feed a character verctor to a function that expects a numeric vector, it fails, period. If you insist in doing this the bad way, then you will have to convert your data at some point. It could even be inside `calculation`: add `x <- as.numeric(x)` as the first line of this function if you wish. Or do this before calling `lapply`. Just do it somewhere. Try `str(mydf1)` if you still have a doubt.

Comment: Yes I understand your point about converting to character.  That is why I wrapped as.data.frame.  And I have spent quite a bit of time exploring what the formatting differences are (hence my earlier comment about listing the dfs a [[]] (mine) and $ (yours). But my terrible df builds are actually irrelevant because the error is the same on straight imported csv files that contain no character data and never have - all numeric doubles all the way.

Comment: @user16469993 Your `as.data.frame` will not change anything. It's still all character afterwards. That's the problem with your reprex. I can't tell anything about your data files, as you don't show it, but you should double check your input data, with `str` at the very least. Always do this with input files you don't know very well. Sometimes, a single non-numeric entry will yield a character column, even though you believe it should be numeric. Importing CSV files can get nasty if you let R guess types.

Comment: Trust me I have spent a lot of time looking at the format differences and trying to work this out before coming back here.  I have added a screenshot of str() of actual data to the post.  Is there a better way of showing the problem, let me know and I will do it.  Thanks again for your time on this.